# How to refactor async code in describe section of mocha test

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocha.js

I need to test in mocha result of async operation that creates array of elements that must comply with some specification grouped in section for readability:

```
describe("tested", async function(){        
    var resultOfOperation = await tested()
    for( var e of resultOfOperation ) {
       describe("feature set 1", function(){
           it("descriptionA", function() {
              assert(true)
           })
           it("descriptionB", function() {
              assert(true)
           })

       })
       describe("feature set 2", function(){
           it("descriptionC", function() {
              assert(true)
           })
       })
    }
})
```

above code doesn't work because `describe` does not support `async` functions so I need to refactor this test case somehow. I know that I can use async function in hooks but it does not help in this case.

How get rid of async in `describe` but retain the structure of test suit for readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement the [delayed root suite](https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite) technique with passing `--delay` flag to your mocha instance, which will give you special `run` function, that you can call whenever your suite is ready to start, can go something like this:

```
(async() => {
  var resultOfOperation = await tested();

  describe("tested", function() {
    for (var e of resultOfOperation) {
      describe("feature set 1", function() {
        it("descriptionA", function() {
          assert(true)
        })
        it("descriptionB", function() {
          assert(true)
        })

      })
      describe("feature set 2", function() {
        it("descriptionC", function() {
          assert(true)
        })
      })
    }
  });

  run();
})();
```